# Access to fetch at '..' from origin '..' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, cors, http-headers

Trying **post** method for my **MERN** application, getting below error. How do I resolve this?

### Full Error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/register' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

### register.js

```
    // this function executes on click of Register button
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/register', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: {
                "hi": "world"
            }
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if(data.status==='success') {
                    console.log(data.status)
                }
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
```

### index.js

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config()
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Add headers before the routes are defined
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type');

    next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        status: 'success'
    });
})
```

Comment: Your server code is working fine, probably cache issue ?. Ensure you have restarted server and clear/disable cache in browser.

Comment: @bogdanoff already tried no good. Somehow ending json using postman works fine I feel something is wrong with my React code.

Comment: I just noticed you have passed an object ( `{ "hi" : "world" }` )  to fetch body property instead of JSON string in .

Answer (score 0):

Below changes to my node.js and React worked for me:

###### Adding cors to my express:

### index.js

```
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions = {
   origin: '*', 
   credentials: true,           
   optionSuccessStatus: 200,
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

###### Stringifying the body and setting 'Content-Type' header to be json:

### Register.js

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/register', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "hi": "world"
            })
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if(data.status==='success') {
                    console.log(data.status)
                }
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
```